# How to overcome maxreceivedmessagesize using php soapclient on linux

Tags: php, linux, soap, maxreceivedmessagesize

Hi I am interrogating a windows service on a remote IIS server from my Linux server using PHP soapclient.
Everything's working fine except when I make a request that returns a large chunk of data, I get the following message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:InternalServiceFault] The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

Is there something I can do with SoapClient to increase this value? I assume that it is at my end that the problem is arising...? Everything I read says to 'increase the MaxReceivedMessageSize in the appropriate web.config or app.config'. I don't have anything like that here on the client-side, just a couple of lines of PHP that make the call using the PHP soap class.

Any help welcome!

Comment: The issue is not on PHP's side, it's on the Windows service side. The IIS administrators would need to increase this value. You could also try to request less from the service as the request is generating too much data

Comment: Yes I did wonder if that were the case -- just got distracted by the ' incoming messages' bit!

Comment: Understood, good luck in your endeavors. I would identify if there's a better API method to use which provides less content. Not sure on the specifics as your question didn't identify what you were using. Multiple calls can be made to the service I would imagine